# Can I convert a rim brake wheel to a disc brake wheel?

Tags: wheels, disc-brake, rim-brake

I recently bought some Roval SLX 24's from eBay.  I made a pretty silly error and didn't check whether they were rim or disc brakes.  I need them to be disc brakes.

Should they be rim brakes, will I be able to convert them to disc brakes for my Cannondale 2015 CAADX Sora?

Comment: We've all done something similar, (or will) so treat it as a learning experience.   Or consider it a chance to buy a rim brake frame and assemble another bike on the Roval wheels....  N+1 and all that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The hub for a disc brake wheel has the mounting for the brake rotor machined into the left side, and has shorter spokes that side to make room for the brake.

If the eBay wheels are for rim brakes, they won’t have these disc mount features out the box. If the spoke counts match and are sufficient, you could theoretically rebuild the rims onto disc specific hubs, but at best you would only be able to reuse half the spokes, quite possibly you’d need to replace the hubs and all the spokes.

It’s not that this can’t be done, but it would probably be less economical in time and money than paying return postage or fees for listing the wheels again on eBay yourself to then buy the right set. You would also have to sell the unwanted hubs and spokes to recover the money sunk into those. It would certainly be more hassle!

Great point from @Rider_X that disc wheels can require higher spoke counts, so that may take the whole exercise off the table anyway. Rim version of these wheels are 20 spoke front, 24 spoke rear, while the disc version is 24 front, 24 rear. In general terms, not having enough spokes on the disc (or any) wheel would be a bad idea.

Comment: I figured this might be the answer.  Shall see when they turn up later this week.

Comment: @Jarede contact the seller immediately - see if you can stop them being shipped and cancel the transaction.  You may have to wear a restocking fee or the auction success fee...

Comment: it's already in the mail... but as you noted above, I could maybe convert the wheelset for my single speed rim bike.

Comment: Disc rims wheels usually have a higher spoke count and often a different spike pattern (especially the front wheel). So a wheel rebuilt isn’t likely a great option.

Comment: Refusing a shipped product will return it for free back to the seller.  If you have the tracking number, contact the courier service and see if you can refuse the package and have it returned.  Don't pick up the product and then spend your own money to return it.

Comment: @Nelson It's maturity to bear the cost of one's own mistakes.

Comment: If the OP still wants to return it, then there is nothing mature about wasting money.  If the advice is simply keep the product, then my advice isn't relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the hubs which pretty much makes the exercise superfluous. Sell them and buy the correct wheels.

Comment: This adds nothing to Swifty's answer.

Answer (score -1):

I did it, 140 mm disc and it's working. Stabel with 4 bolts. Front one it's not possiable, too narrow.

Comment: That’s interesting. Can you explain how, and what do you mean by 4 bolts?

Comment: Welcome to the site - This answer would be improved by adding a photo of your wheel with [edit]

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. We're looking for answers with [more detail](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please consider editing your answer to explain the process. What hub did you start with? Were you able to re-use any of the spokes? Did you have to buy additional spokes? A short, one-line answer like this is likely to get downvoted, flagged for moderator intervention, and possibly deleted.